# Print to output file hash:relativePath/filename

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to get file list, calculate their hashes and print it on an external file *.info* with powershell.
The file must be like (one row example):

4bfc12adfe4842bf07b657f0369c4cb522955686:dist/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar

The separator **:** is **mandatory** (it'll be used by a parser later).
I tried different types of scripts, but without complete result.

Here i get a good file only with hash, but i can't find a way to add *:relativepath\filename*

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 -Path (
        Get-ChildItem "$WorkPath" -Recurse -Force | 
        ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}).Hash        | 
        Out-File -FilePath "$WorkPath\us\update.info"
```

here second:

```
Get-ChildItem "$WorkPath" -Recurse -Force | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 | Select-Object Hash, Path | Out-File -FilePath "$WorkPath\us\update.info"
```

I tried to remove `Select-Object Hash, Path` or only `Hash, Path` to remove title, but it prints Algorithm too...
With complete command:

```
Hash  Path
----  ----
```

Withouth that part:

```
Algorithm    Hash    Path
---------    ----    ----
```

I specify that file must contains only hash:relativepath/filename, not heading or another elements.
Someone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to fetch all files:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Recurse -Force -File
```

Calculate the hash for each file and add it to output file:

```
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $FileHash = Get-FileHash -Path $File.FullName -Algorithm SHA1
    Add-Content -Path $Output -Value "$($FileHash.Hash):$($File.FullName)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick, you solved my problem!